# Ive sent BNB from my metamask BSC network to my gnosis safe contract ETH network version 1.1.1

Tags: bsc, proxy-contracts, factory

Good evening guys i have a problem and i will try to explain it.

1. BNB on my metamask wallet
2. sent BNB from BSC network to my gnosis safe eth contract
3. how can y replay the transaction if my error was made on the version 1.1.1
4. The factory proxies for chain BSC 56* is only on the version 1.3.0
5. How can I replay the transaction if theres no HEX to replay on the main HASH.